# How do I tell when I'm stealing things?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

On a loading screen, I read that stealing items can lead to consequences in the future. How do I tell whether an item I'm targeting is considered "stealing" or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Items that you are stealing will have a red outline around the name of the item. There are only a few of these items in the game and stealing them usually results in NPC's around you becoming hostile where they were not before.

Comment: Also, the text that pops up will say "steal" instead of the usual "search".

Comment: I just verified this, instead of 'search cash register' the text will pop up as 'steal from cash register'. The first time you come across stealing is the first time you reach Soldiers Field, a message will pop up warning that stealing will have consequences.

Comment: I ran across a gift box (containing Gear) that had a red outline, but still said "Search Gift Box" rather than "Steal Gift Box". I assumed that I could just look at the Gear and not steal it, but it aggro'd the nearby NPCs anyway.

Comment: In ShantyTown, all I did was look at some guy *(behind a table, on the way left-side of town after leaving the elevator)* and he said "Thieving bastard!" and started shooting at me.  I didn't even go behind the table.  I think the stealing logic in this game is messed up...