# Are there different Bioshock Infinite endings depending on choices? Do choices make any difference?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

The original bioshock had different endings based on certain morality choices, namely whether you saved or harvested little sisters if I recall.

I just finished Infinite and I'm wondering if there are any other endings.

** **There will likely be spoilers in the answers, don't scroll down if you haven't finished it******

What about the choices like whether or not you stole from the shops? More obviously, what about the choice between the cage and the bird necklace? Do they change anything? Did anyone pick the cage?

Comment: Ah you are indeed correct. There's a collary to this question that I'd like to add in an edit if that's okay.

Comment: Your question is still a complete duplicate of that other question. Yours is just more specific, asking about particular actions that might affect the ending

Comment: @NathanTempelman What would you like me to add? I'll see if I can accomodate your request

Comment: @Retrosaur Since he added some information in an edit when he made that comment, I'm guessing that that's the additional information.

Comment: About your added questions, see: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112633/what-are-the-consequences-of-stealing-in-bioshock-infinite and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110650/elizabeths-brooch-does-the-one-i-pick-matter

Comment: Ah, right you are. I had just heard that every time you play the game, it's different on account of Elizabeth's hundreds of thousands of variable lines of dialog. I was wondering what would affect the story, and whether it was worth playing again for that reason.